# Disable ASP.NET MVC route for Url resolving

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I use the following route configuration in my MVC project:

```
var json = routes.MapRoute(
    name: "DefaultJson",
    url: "json/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { ... }
);

json.DataTokens["force-json-result"] = new object();

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { ... }
);
```

This is used in a dev environment, the idea is to allow the view designers to see the entire model passed to the view without having Visual Studio.

If I use the Url resolver the first route will be used. For example, the following command

```
@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")
```

will print

```
/json/Controller/Action
```

Is there any way to ignore my first route during Url resolving?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use [Url.RouteUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.routeurl%28v=vs.118%29.aspx). Using that you can specify a particular route name and then generate the url.

Comment: I ended using query string because of other difficulties. But this seem to be best solution.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to do what you're asking but have solved the problem in a different way by adding a piece to my layout page which will output the model in json to a hidden div when the site is in development mode.

The same information is available and the developer doesn't have to switch urls to debug.